# Cambiar dinamicamente / Intercalar imagenes a través de un button - jQuery

Tags: jquery

**jQuery** - Cambiar dinámicamente imágenes a través de un botón.

Deseo tener un botón que al pulsar cambie una imagen X por una imagen Y, previamente no existe imagen.

Pasos a seguir:

```
1) Tenemos un botón para ser pulsado (aún no se ha cargado ninguna imagen).
1) Pulsamos botón --> Aparece la imagen X
2) Pulsamos botón --> Aparece la imagen Y (desaparece la imagen X).
3) Pulsamos botón --> Aparece la imagen X (desaparece la imagen Y).
4) Así sucesivamente...
```

Código jQuery - HTML - JS

```
//Intercalar dos imagenes.
    $("#intercalar_2_imagenes").click(function() {
        //Creamos una imagen con la cara de Isco.
        var img1 = new Image();
        var src1 = 'isco.png';
        img1.src = src1;

        //Creamos una imagen con la cara de Torres.
        var img2 = new Image();
        var src2 = 'torres.png';
        img2.src = src2;

        $('#imagen').append(img1);

        if ($('#imagen').append(img1)==true)
            $('#imagen').append(img2);
        else
            $('#imagen').append(img1);
    });
```

Me aparece de inicio sin imagen, bien. Pulso el botón y me aparece la imagen X, vuelvo a pulsar el botón pero me vuelve a mostrar la imagen X al lado de la primera imagen X, ¿dónde está el error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo dos variables `src` para cada una de las imagenes.

Al pulsar el boton solo añade la imagen si no hay nada en el `div`

Y para cambiar compruebo que `src` tiene la foto del div con `$('#imagen>img').attr("src")`

**Nota:** Y solo porque me apetecia, el botón se llama Crear pero cuando ya ha creado una imagen, se llama Cambiar hehehe

---

**Update**

Puse un `setInterval` cada 3 segundos para que haga click en el boton si su valor es "cambiar" (lo cual significa que ya existen las fotos)

```js
$("#intercalar_2_imagenes").click(function() {


  var img = new Image();

  var src1 = 'http://dogtowndogtraining.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/300x300-061-e1340955308953.jpg';
  var src2 = "https://c1.staticflickr.com/4/3487/5816558694_451cce568b.jpg";



  if ($('#imagen').html() == "") { //no hay foto

    img.src = src1;
    $('#imagen').append(img);
    $(this).val("cambiar");

  } else { // hay foto

    if ($('#imagen>img').attr("src") == src1)
      $('#imagen>img').attr("src", src2);
    else
      $('#imagen>img').attr("src", src1);

  }
});



setInterval(function() {
  if ($("#intercalar_2_imagenes").val() == "cambiar") {
    $("#intercalar_2_imagenes").click();
    console.log("cambiada");
  }
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="intercalar_2_imagenes" value="Crear">

<div id="imagen"></div>
```

Si quieres que itere sobre varias, puedes crear un array de fotos.

Cuando la creas asignas la primera foto y cuando vas a cambiarla, miras el indice que ocupa el `src` actual en el array de fotos y coges la siguiente

Si la foto es la ultima, vuelves al indice `0`

**Ejemplo varias imagenes:**

```js
$("#intercalar_2_imagenes").click(function() {


  var img = new Image();
  
  var fotos = [
   'http://dogtowndogtraining.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/300x300-061-e1340955308953.jpg',
    "https://c1.staticflickr.com/4/3487/5816558694_451cce568b.jpg",
    "https://image.freepik.com/vector-gratis/calaveras-de-azucar-patrones-de-costura-paquetes-de-vectores-florales-regalo-de-promocion_639302.jpg"
  ];

  
  
  if ($('#imagen').html() == "") { //no hay foto
  img.src = fotos[0];
    $('#imagen').append(img);
    $(this).val("cambiar");
  } else {// hay foto

    var fotoActual = $('#imagen>img').attr("src")  ;
    var siguienteFoto = fotos.indexOf(fotoActual)+1;

    if(siguienteFoto >= fotos.length) siguienteFoto = 0; //si la siguiente foto es la ultima
    $('#imagen>img').attr("src", fotos[siguienteFoto]) ;
    

  }
});

setInterval(function() {
  if ($("#intercalar_2_imagenes").val() == "cambiar") {
    $("#intercalar_2_imagenes").click();
    //console.log("cambiada");
  }
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="intercalar_2_imagenes" value="Crear">

<div id="imagen"></div>
```

Comment: ¿y si queremos aplicarle un tiempo... cada x segundos que cambie de foto? Debería aplicarse setTimeOut(milisegundos); ¿no?

Comment: @omaza1990 sip o interval

Comment: El problema viene a... ¿dónde aplico el settimeout?

Comment: @omaza1990 ya está listo el  `setInterval`

Comment: Muchas gracias, al final lo conseguí ayer mismo jajajaja. :) Una cosita: ¿Cómo se haría para por ejemplo, intercambiar el segundo párrafo por el tercer párrafo, es decir que cambien de orden, uno arriba y otro abajo?

Answer (score 2):

Hola el problema esta en que cada vez que aprietas el botón ,declarras dos variables, y estas agregando sucesivamente las imagenes sin borrar la anterior. INtenta lo siguiente.

```js
$(document).ready(function (){

        
        var src1 = 'https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--72zwNb-Z--/c_scale,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/ik94so7cfpzyni8rqvsc.jpg';
        
        var src2 = 'http://public21.es/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/PROGRAMACION-WEB.jpg';


    $("#intercalar_2_imagenes").click(function() {
    
        if($("#imagen").attr("src")==""){
            $("#imagen").attr("src",src1);
        }else if($("#imagen").attr("src")==src1){
            $("#imagen").attr("src",src2);
        }else{
          $("#imagen").attr("src",src1);
        }
        
       
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imagenContenedor">
  <img id="imagen" />
</div>
<button id="intercalar_2_imagenes">intercalar</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Aquí te dejo una solución que te permitirá hacerlo con las imágenes que quieras de un modo práctico:

**HTML**:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="image"></div>
<button id="cambiar">Cambiar</button>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var pos = 0;

        var img1 = {
            src: 'http://www.todopaisajes.com/Imagenes/paisaje-rural-del-campo.jpg'
        };

        var img2 = {
            src: 'http://www.poesi.as/cuadros/mar.jpg'
        };

        var img3 = {
            src: 'http://www.royaltyfreelandscapesimages.com/imagenes/desierto/desierto_g/Atardecer-en-el-Desierto.jpg'
        };

        var images = [img1,img2,img3]; //Aqui deberas meter los objetos (que después serán imágenes) que desees que se muestren

        for (var i=0; i < images.length; i++) {
            var img = new Image(); //Creamos una imagen
            img.src = images[i].src; //Le metemos en el src la url del objeto
            images[i] = img; //Metemos la variable en forma de imagen (convertimos el objeto en una imagen)
        }

        $('#image').empty().append(images[pos]); //Inicialmente cargamos la primera imagen

        $("#cambiar").click(function() {
            pos++; //Sumamos una posición en el array
            if (pos > images.length-1) {pos = 0;} //Si el valor de pos es mayor que la posición máxima del array volvemos a 0
            $('#image').empty().append(images[pos]); //Limpiamos el div y le metemos la nueva imagen
        });
});
```

> ¿Por qué he usado objetos? Como en tu anterior pregunta también
>   mencionabas que cambiarías más parámetros a cada imagen como por
>   ejemplo su ancho, podrías para cada imagen añadir (por ejemplo) un
>   ancho personalizado a cada una, lo cual tan solo tendrías que hacer el
>   siguiente cambio (te pongo el ejemplo con **un solo objeto** y la
>   correspondiente edición del **loop for**):

```
//El cambio en el objeto
var img1 = {
     src: 'http://www.todopaisajes.com/Imagenes/paisaje-rural-del-campo.jpg',
     width: 200
};

//Cambio del for
for (var i=0; i < images.length; i++) {
     var img = new Image(); //Creamos una imagen
     img.src = images[i].src; //Le metemos en el src la url del objeto
     img.width = images[i].width; //Aplicamos también un ancho a la imagen
     images[i] = img;
}
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda